# Dynamically accesing a button and creating a list Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Alright, so I am stuck. So the break down of the project is when you enter your age, and select an option from the drop down list when you click add, a list is created and that input is plugged into the list. I have to also show that list somewhere on the page. I hope I explained that correctly.

Anyways, I've been trying everything from trying to create a new div, to creating an unordered list programmatically, and trying to display it within the body under the last div, but my code below doesn't execute when I hit the add button. By the way I CAN NOT edit the HTML in anyway and I CAN NOT use JQuery. I have to use pure Javascript. Any tips or help would be great!

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";

var add = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
add.onlick = 'addToList()';


var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";

var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];
dropDown.type = "option";
dropDown.required = true;

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

//var title = document.createElement("h2");
//title = "Member List";
//newDiv.appendChild(title);*

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
newDiv.appendChild(ul);


function addToList() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  //li.setAttribute('id', age.value + dropDown.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(age.value + ' ' + dropDown.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);

  return false;

}
```

```html
<h1>Household List</h1>
<div class="builder">
  <o class="household"></o>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Age
          <input type="text" name="age">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Relationship
          <select name="rel">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="self">Self</option>
            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
            <option value="child">Child</option>
            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Smoker?
          <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add">add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<pre class="debug"></pre>
```

Comment: You can’t assign a string as an event handler.  Use `add.onclick = addToList;`, or better, `add.addEventListener("click", addToList);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some syntactical errors in the code, especially the button click event handler. Here is the correct code.

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";

var add = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
add[0].onclick = addToList;


var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";

var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];
dropDown.type = "option";
dropDown.required = true;

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

//var title = document.createElement("h2");
//title = "Member List";
//newDiv.appendChild(title);*

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
newDiv.appendChild(ul);


function addToList() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  //li.setAttribute('id', age.value + dropDown.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(age.value + ' ' + dropDown.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);

  return false;

}
```

```html
<h1>Household List</h1>
<div class="builder">
  <ol class="household"></o>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Age
          <input type="text" name="age">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Relationship
          <select name="rel">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="self">Self</option>
            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
            <option value="child">Child</option>
            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Smoker?
          <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add">add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<pre class="debug"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues in your code

1. All the for attributes and input attributes can be defined the html instead of using js
2. `button` type default is submit ,so add `button type="button"` in `<button class="add">add</button>`
3. `add.onlick = 'addToList()'`; is wrong ;the function is not a string , replace it with `document.getElementsByClassName('add')[0].onclick = addToList;`

```js
var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0];
var dropDown = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0];

var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "houseMem");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);


var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.setAttribute("id", "memList");
newDiv.appendChild(ul);

document.getElementsByClassName('add')[0].onclick = addToList;

function addToList() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(age.value + ' ' + dropDown.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  return false;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Household List</h1>
  <div class="builder">
    <o class="household"></o>
    <form method="POST" action="form-handler">
      <div>
        <label>Age
          <input type="number" name="age" min="0" max="120">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Relationship
          <select name="rel" required>
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="self">Self</option>
            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
            <option value="child">Child</option>
            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Smoker?
          <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="add" type="button">add</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but I am unable to make changes to the HTML per project specifications. Could I add a type to the add button such as: add.type = ('button'); ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your HTML you have an o tag instead of an order list tag. This may fix the code. Also when you click on the add button the form is posted so I would remove the post until the end.